# Rails 3.2 - How to merge params without displaying everything in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, redirect, controller

In my app I have a `/thanks` page that users were originally redirected to when completing a certain action. Now I want to redirect them to this page after multiple kinds of events and render different partials based on what the event was. So I added this to the `/thanks` page:

```
- case @event
  - when "reservation"
    = render 'thanks_job_created'
  - when "charge"
    = render 'thanks_job_charged'
```

Then, in the the `JobsController#create` action, I changed `redirect_to thanks_jobs_path` to this:

```
redirect_to thanks_jobs_path(params.merge(event: "reservation"))
```

...and added `@event = params[:event]` to `JobsController#thanks`.

The behavior works as intended, but I've found that using `params.merge` this way now displays every paramter in the URL, including authenticity token of the `#create` form, all of the Job attributes, etc. Before the URL looked correct (`/jobs/thanks`) because the only params were `action` and `controller` which are already indicated in the URL.

Is there a way for me to use `params.merge` without displaying all of that info in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to pass the event as a parameter, you don't need to use `params.merge` at all.

```
redirect_to thanks_jobs_path(event: "reservation")
```

will give you the path `/jobs/thanks?event=reservation`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `except`:

```
params.merge.except(:auth_token)
```

In your situation:

```
redirect_to thanks_jobs_path(params.merge(event: "reservation").except(:auth_token))
```